# Pytorch CUDA out of memory despite plenty of memory left

Tags: python, pytorch

I am training a Huggingface model using their trainer Python module. To be fair, I have refactored my code a bit, but a very similar code was actually working perfectly with way larger datasets than the one I am supplying right now, as well as higher **per_device_train_batch_size** (now equal to 8, still crashing, 16 used to work).

However, I am getting out of memory error, which is pretty weird...

```
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 20.00 MiB (GPU 0; 8.00 GiB total capacity; 1.54 GiB already allocated; 5.06 GiB free; 1.62 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF
```

That error is what got me wondering, because it's trying to allocate 20.00 MiB and 5.06 GiB is seemingly free, so why does it crash?

My PyTorch version is '1.12.1+cu113', after I run `torch.version.cuda` I get 11.3

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your CUDA drive is not set up correctly.

You need to install these two correctly also as a prereq
NVIDIA CUDA 11.0 or above
NVIDIA cuDNN v7 or above

Comment: Thanks! You were right, I had something messed up with my CUDA installation. Super weird error though, because it worked on smaller datasets :D